# Avoiding to create a duplicate object in php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way to avoid creates duplicate object name without using loop?

```
$venue = array();

if(loop for checking duplicate OBJ){
        $temp = some_var which fetch from database;

        //If it's not a duplicate object, creates new object 
        $venue["$temp"] = new Venue($temp);
        $venue["$temp"]->do something;
    }
    else{
        //If it's a duplicate object, don't creates new object
        $venue["$temp"]->do something;
    }
```

I'm trying to check duplicate object name("name") by using loop like this:

//checks name of each object in venue's array that Is it duplicate?

```
for($itr = 0;$itr < $count($venue);$itr+=1){
        if($venue["$temp"]->name === $name){ 
            return true; //If it's a duplicate object name return true
        }
}
```

The problem is when I using this loop to check, It consume a lot of time to finish the work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is to use another array to collect all names as array keys:

```
$allNames[$venue["$temp"]->name] = null;
```

Then check if it's a duplicate object name by using:

```
array_key_exists($allNames, $name);
```

Comment: Thanks, better than mine